# ActiveX Controls Crash Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Access crashes the moment I try and add an ActiveX control to a stacked layout form in MS Access 2007.

**Steps to recreate issue:**

1. Create a table
2. Select table from object panel
3. Create form (which creates a default form for all columns)
4. Switch to design view for form
5. Select ActiveX controls, and drag a calendar control to the form (doesn't matter which)
6. Drag calendar control somewhere into the stacked layout of the default form
7. Switch to form view
8. Access crashes

As long as I leave the control outside of a stacked layout, it will work just fine. The very second I add it to a stacked layout…crash.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have the same problem in Access 2007 SP3